# Wrong query representation in laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have this code to get events which is in current year:

```
$year = "YEAR('".date('Y/m/d')."')";
$event = Event::where('date_start', $year);
var_dump($event->toSql());
```

But the query representation of the code is as follows:

```
"select * from `events` where `date_start` = ? and `events`.`deleted_at` is null"
```

Why is that? Where my mistake?

Comment: now whats wrong with this query? the question mark?

Comment: What is wrong with the query? Note that this is a prepared statement. The placeholder `?` will be "replaced" with `$year` when you execute the query.

Comment: with that code above, the result is null event if the condition is true

Comment: What is the data type of `date_start`?

Comment: Code issues aside, the query won't produce the desired results unless date_start only contains the year. Also, why the convoluted way to get the year? ```YEAR('".date('Y/m/d')."')"``` could simply be ```date('Y')```

Comment: data column is date, and data type is date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the records with specific year in a `datetime` type field of MySQL, you can use Eloquent's [`whereYear()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereYear):

```
$year = 2017;
$event = Event::whereYear('date_start', '=', $year)->get();
```

Or obviously `$year = date("Y")` if you want events from current year!

Comment: Another way could be `whereRaw('year(date_start) = year(now())')`.